# I am using paytm as gateway, working properly, but when amount comes with decimals then its giving an issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, paytm

I am using paytm as gateway, working properly, but when amount comes with decimals then its giving an error like..

"mdecrypt_generic(): An empty string was passed"

I am using two paytm config files:

require_once("paytm/config_paytm.php");

require_once("paytm/encdec_paytm.php");

I used round() & number_format() php functions for that.. then its working.. but i want my real amount (with decimals)

Is there any setting for amount with decimals (for paytm)

Answer (score 0):

You should change Init settings

```
cookies.encrypt = false
```

hope it will work for you.

Comment: but where I should paste it?